# Build a installation wrapper for my application

Tags: windows

SO I have a application that is a simple installer that use a flag at the end of it like so:

CLIENTSETUP.EXE /BLAH

My goal is to build a install wrapper for it so I don't always have to open a command prompt to run it. I want to be able to just double click to run it.

I'm not exactly sure where to go from here and what to use. Someone told me C# would be there best one to use but maybe there is a easier way?

Comment: MS-Windows really really really needs a software management system like all other systems. This questions reads like from the 16th century... (no offense meant).

Comment: No offense taken :) This really is just a project for me. This is not for a mass deployment or anything

Comment: Ok, though even then it definitely would make sense. So much more secure and easier. But you have no choice when using MS-Windows... :-)